# c++ .h inclusion of classes and .cpp from one class passing through to another class

Tags: c++

new to c++ having a hard time understanding when inherited classes break the compiler so I'm trying to construct a player class and pass it to the core class then use the core class to create the objects

**errors:**

```
./core.h:6:12: error: expected unqualified-id
class Core public: Player {
           ^
app.cpp:6:8: error: variable has incomplete type 'Core'
  Core core;
       ^
./core.h:6:7: note: forward declaration of 'Core'
class Core public: Player {
```

**app.cpp**

```
#include "core.h"

int main()
{
  Core core;
  core.Player(..);
  core.Player(..);
  std::cout << core.GetStringValue(..);
}
```

**Player.cpp**

```
#include "core.h"
#include "PlayerKeys.h"

class Player {
  private:
     .... initialized variables
  public:
    ... functions 
   One function calls a function from Core.Datetime
}
```

**core.h**

```
#ifndef Core_H
#define Core_H
class Core public: Player {
  public:
    ...
};

#endif
```

**core.cpp**

```
class Core{

  public:
  std::string DevlopmentTeamAccessDailyHash(){
    ...
  }
  std::sting SystemAccessActiveHash(){
    ...
  }
  std::string CurrentDateAndTime(){
    ...
  }

}
```

Comment: I wrote an answer for your syntactical error, but are you sure you want this inheritance? Why do you think it makes sense?

Comment: @birdfreeyahoo im in new to the language and lower-level code I have been studying devs ops and I'm trying to figure out a design practice thats works that I can at least understand can you elaborate on why this scheme is not the best practice or perhaps a reference to a different practical approach  ?

Comment: How is a core a player? Why does Player depent on a function of its subclass?

Comment: can you just edit your question and show the constructor of what your player looks like. you reduced to the code to a degree its becoming an XY problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your core.cpp and player.cpp files contain the class declaration. they are not for class declaration. they should contain the class definitions.

for example your core.cpp should look something like this.

```
#include "core.h"

Core::Core()
{
//...
}

std::string Core::DevlopmentTeamAccessDailyHash()
{
//...
}
```

while your header looks something like this

```
#ifndef Core_H
#define Core_H
class Core : public Player //note that you place the : in wrong place
{
public:
  Core(); 
  std::string DevlopmentTeamAccessDailyHash(); 
    ...
};

#endif
```

Edit : you mentioned in comments you want to pass some arguments to the constructor of `Player` through `Core`

I assume this is what you wanted to do with this call.

`core.Player(..);`

this call is not a valid way to call the player constructor.
You could perhaps do  `core.Player::Player(your arguments)` but this is again not how OOP works.

instead you modify the `Core` constructor so it takes all the parameters it needs

in header file (Core.h)

```
   Core::Core(parameters ...);
```

in cpp file (Core.cpp)

```
 Core::Core(parameters ...)
 {
   Player::Player(parameters passed as arguments...);
   //do core stuff..
 }
```

Comment: won't this cause in error in the constructor its expecting parameters.`Player("Screenname 1", core.CurrentDateAndTime(), "publickey1", "Privatekey1", 1, 1000, 1, 1, 1);`

Comment: as far as i can tell his constructor doesnt have a param in main `Core core;`

Comment: core doesn't Player does, **Player** is expecting parameters not the core.

Comment: @YoungNateFrmTTDT ah.. this...  `core.Player()` but this is not a valid C++ syntax to call base constructor.  I think what he wanted to do is perhaps access the `core.Player::functionname()`. hard to tell.

Comment: @YoungNateFrmTTDT also cant tell what your Player constructor looks like with the question in hand.

Comment: thats exactly what  want do access anything passed in by the core

Comment: @YoungNateFrmTTDT Edited my answer further. you just modify the constructor of Core with the params you want to pass. and then within the Core constructor you pass them to the Player constructor

Comment: your answer helped me so much thank you . I ultimately decided to go with the friend class method as I understood it instantly

Answer (score 0):

```
class Core : public Player {
```

Just put the colon before public. A simple syntactical error. Also don't forget to include `player.h` in your `core.h` (You may have to move the Player class declaration to a header file if it only resides in a .cpp-File).